# jQuery UI Autocomplete Plugin: set source after minLength?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

RE: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete

When a user types enough characters to satisfy `minLength`, is there an event that is triggered? I need to respond to that event, make a call to my server to get the auto complete values, and set that as `source`. I'm not sure how to do this. Snippet of code is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jquery-ui autocomplete source can be one of 3 things - an array of local things to search, a string that is a URL to query from, or a custom function. It sounds like you'll be able to do what you need just from setting the source equal to a URL. Jquery will automatically query that URL (appending &term=) after your minLength has been passed. Your server is then responsible for responding with the values to be autocompleted against.

Here are lots of good examples
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#default

Comment: spike, I didn't realize the plugin would automatically use `source` once `minLength` condition is met. I'll probably need to use a function as the web service I am using does not support `&term=`.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation:
http://www.jensbits.com/2010/03/29/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-with-php-and-mysql/

If you need something special, you can look for change event (documentation here http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ ) where you can count input value length and call another function if input value length is equal to minLength.